# Search Facebook api not working with email

Tags: java, android, eclipse, facebook-graph-api

Is there any way with `Graph api of Facebook` using which I can pass an email parameter and I can get at least Facebook profile page and Facebook Id of the user?

E.g If i have an email `xxx@gmail.com` and I want to search the profile page registered on this email and its `Facebook ID.`

I have tried this sort of search but It didn't work

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=email&type=post
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont see email on the API, it may not be allowed?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/search/#types

Answer (score 1):

If you're an app and you have the right permissions, you can get the users email address with

```
me?fields=name,email
```

(try with the [API explorer here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/370347259742770/?method=GET&path=me?fields=name,email))

It's not possible to get the user's friend's email address or find email addresses through the search api.

Answer (score 0):

`type=post` is for post search, you should try using

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=email_to_search&type=user
```

Which will search into users instead of posts